# Prevent or clear video cache IE11 and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

Can anyone help identify where Windows 8.1 + IE11 are caching video files?  I want to clear just video files from the cache and cannot find where they are stored.  I can find plenty of examples of where they are stored with Windows 7, but that doesn't appear to be the correct location any more.

Comment: What type of videos? IE11 Desktop or IE11 Modern UI. The location of your cache `Temp` directory is within your user profile for both.  If we are talking about a Flash video that is stored in a different location.

Comment: web videos (i.e. .mp4) played in <video> tag of web site.  IE Desktop Mode, but I guess would be nice to identify for both modes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it by using PowerShell and the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.  In my case I knew it was a pretty big file (and most other files on my system are not as large), so I simply filtered where file was of certain size.  I also include hidden/system files (-Force) and prevent error messages from being displayed (mostly just access denied messages).  I am an administrator on my machine and I ran the following in Administrator mode:

```
cd "C:\"

Get-ChildItem -recurse -Force -ErrorAction 0 | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 500000000}
```

I found my IE11 cache for video files here:

**C:\Users[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Low\IE\X295M8MC**

I suspect that last folder name changes per user/machine/timeframe.